# S3 copy vs upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

What is the best way to copy contents of one S3 folder to another using boto3 python client ? I am trying to evaluate boto3 s3 client `copy` vs `upload_file` .

Is one more performance efficient over another ?
Under what scenarios one is preferred over another?

Answer (score 1):

To copy an object in Amazon S3, you can use the [`copy_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object) command.

This works:

- In the same or different buckets
- In the same or different regions
- In the same or different accounts

The command is sent to the **destination bucket**, which then "pulls" the object from the source bucket. There is no need to download/upload the object, so it works fast and does not consume your bandwidth.

The only situation in which a download/upload might be preferable to a Copy might be where it is not possible to give **both GET permissions on the source bucket and PUT permissions on the destination bucket** for the same set of credentials.